# I am trying to use Twilio in a python script but when I try to install the package I get an error

Tags: ssl, installation, twilio

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/90/68/e643d8f8a00847c1c5284c7eab68405df4b45570da72eb4a2254c4f5a326/twilio-7.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)')))

I am using PyCharm and all I'm doing is clicking on install package when I hover over the red squiggly underline of twilio. I'm very new to this to any help would be appriciated.

I don't know what to try.

Answer (score 0):

you start by updating the ca-certificates package on your system, either with yum or apt install.(e.g. `sudo apt install ca-certificates`)

It's also better to install the package in a virtual environment, e.g. by using:

```
python3 -m venv new_env
source new_env/bin/activate
pip install twilio
```

If above doesn't work, you can install it by bypassing the ssl check (not recommended though)

```
pip install --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org twilio
```